# Discord.js client missing intents

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 bots that I'm bringing back from deprecated, one works fine, the other one keeps giving me an error for client missing intents. Thing is I put the intents in there, like the other bot but it just won't work and I don't know why.
A helping hand please?
The bash:

```
Administrator@ServRemu MINGW64 /c/Bots/Rin-master
$ node index.js
C:\Bots\Rin-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:544
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Bots\Rin-master\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (C:\Bots\Rin-master\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Bots\Rin-master\index.js:6:23)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  [←[32mSymbol(code)←[39m]: ←[32m'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'←[39m
}
```

and here's the whole index.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config');
const fs = require('fs');
const Enmap = require("enmap");
const discordClient = new Discord.Client();


const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES,
    ]
  });

fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
        let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
        discordClient.on(eventName, event.bind(null, discordClient));
    });
});

discordClient.commands = new Enmap();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
        let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
        discordClient.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
});


discordClient.login(config.discordApiToken);
```